# Have vote count in newsletter

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

When looking at SE newsletters emailed to me I often like looking at the top questions for the week, however there is a problem, I always look and wonder how many upvotes (subtracting the downvotes from the amount of course) there were on the questions, but I am not interested enough to go to each of the pages and check, I am just curious, so I think that it would be good if the vote count for questions could be displayed in the newsletter too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean "just upvotes, ignoring the effects of downvotes", that's not displayed anywhere on the site that I know of, so I don't see why it should be in the newsletter.  You always have to click for that; the site displays the *net* votes.

If you just mean that you want scores for both questions and answers, they're already there:

[image: weekly newsletter screen shot]

Comment: I meant the upvotes (including the effect of downvotes). I had not noticed that this was already displayed, but can I suggest that it be made more obvious in some way.

Comment: @Par you can edit your feature request to reflect this then.

Comment: @Sha probably be better as a new question? Because this is now answered...?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ hmm... edge case but yeah might be better.